# Error crar una entidad con Identity - Net Core 3

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, identity, dotnetcore

Estoy usando Identity por primera vez por lo que estoy tratando de entender algunas cosas.

Tengo una entidad relacionada con otras entidades, en este caso la clase Evolución que es la que registra la evolución de pacientes internados:

```
public class Evolucion
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    public DateTime FechaEvolucion { get; set; }
    public int IngresoId { get; set; }
    public int ServicioInternacionId { get; set; }
    public int CamaInternacionId { get; set; }
    public int ExamenFisicoId { get; set; }
    public string UsuarioId { get; set; }

    public virtual Ingreso Ingreso { get; set; }
    public virtual Servicio ServicioInternacion { get; set; }
    public virtual Cama CamaInternacion { get; set; }
    public virtual ExamenFisico ExamenFisico { get; set; }
    public virtual Usuario Usuario { get; set; }

    public Evolucion() { ; }

    public Evolucion(DateTime fechaEvolucion, int ingresoId, int servicioInternacionId, int camaInternacionId, int examenFisicoId, string usuarioId)
    {
        FechaEvolucion = fechaEvolucion;
        IngresoId = ingresoId;
        ServicioInternacionId = servicioInternacionId;
        CamaInternacionId = camaInternacionId;
        ExamenFisicoId = examenFisicoId;
        UsuarioId = usuarioId;
    }
}
```

El problema que tengo es que al intentar crear una evolución del paciente intenta crear los objetos *Camas, Ingresos y Servicios* que ya existen en sus tablas, entonces me lanza este error al intentar insertar un valor en una columna de identidad:

> "Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in table 'Camas' when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF.\r\n
> Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in table 'Ingresos' when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF.\r\n
> Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in table 'Servicios' when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF."

¿Como hago para que no intente insertar esots objetos?
Lo único que necesito es que guarde los valores que están en el constructor de la clase.

Este es el Controller

```
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public IActionResult Create(Evolucion model)
    {
        try
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                model.UsuarioId = _userManager.GetUserAsync(User).Result.Id;
                model.IngresoId = model.Ingreso.Id;
                model.ServicioInternacionId = model.ServicioInternacion.Id;
                model.CamaInternacionId = model.CamaInternacion.Id;
                model.ExamenFisicoId = model.ExamenFisico.Id;
                _logic.Add(model);
                return RedirectToAction("Index","Ingreso");
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return RedirectToAction("Error", ex);
        }
        ViewBag.Servicios = _logic.GetServicios().Select(g => new SelectListItem() { Text = g.Descripcion, Value = g.Id.ToString() }).ToList();
        ViewBag.Camas = _logic.GetCamas().Select(g => new SelectListItem() { Text = g.Descripcion, Value = g.Id.ToString() }).ToList();
        ViewBag.IngresoId = model.Ingreso.Id;
        return View(model);
    }
```

**EDIT**

Hice unas correcciones en la entidad:

```
public class Evolucion
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    [DisplayName("Fecha de Evolución")]
    public DateTime FechaEvolucion { get; set; }
    public virtual Ingreso Ingreso { get; set; }
    [DisplayName("Servicio")]
    public virtual Servicio ServicioInternacion { get; set; }
    [DisplayName("Cama")]
    public virtual Cama CamaInternacion { get; set; }
    public virtual ExamenFisico ExamenFisico { get; set; }
    public virtual Usuario Usuario { get; set; }
}
```

En el Controller:

```
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public IActionResult Create(Evolucion model)
    {
        try
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                model.Usuario = _userManager.GetUserAsync(this.User).Result;
                _logic.Add(model);
                return RedirectToAction("Index","Ingreso");
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return RedirectToAction("Error", ex);
        }
        ViewBag.Servicios = _logic.GetServicios().Select(g => new SelectListItem() { Text = g.Descripcion, Value = g.Id.ToString() }).ToList();
        ViewBag.Camas = _logic.GetCamas().Select(g => new SelectListItem() { Text = g.Descripcion, Value = g.Id.ToString() }).ToList();
        ViewBag.IngresoId = model.Ingreso.Id;
        return View(model);
    }
```

Y en la lógica al crear la entidad:

```
    public void Add(Evolucion entidad)
    {
        Servicio servicio = _unitOfWork.Servicios.Get(entidad.ServicioInternacion.Id);
        entidad.ServicioInternacion = servicio;
        Cama cama = _unitOfWork.Camas.Get(entidad.CamaInternacion.Id);
        entidad.CamaInternacion = cama;
        Ingreso ingreso = _unitOfWork.Ingresos.Get(entidad.Ingreso.Id);
        entidad.Ingreso = ingreso;
        _unitOfWork.Evoluciones.Add(entidad);
        _unitOfWork.Complete();
    }
```

Ahora el error que tengo es parecido, evidentemente está intentando crear un nuevo usuario con el Id que ya existe:

> "Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK_Usuario'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.Usuario'. The duplicate key value is ('userId').\r\nThe statement has been terminated."

**Aclaración**
La clase Usuario y la clase Evolución están en distintos contextos.

Comment: Que es ese mapeo que realizas ? me parece que es redundante.

Comment: Te referis a los campos Id de las clases virtuales?

Comment: No me refiero a esas asignaciones de ids que realizas en el método Create().

Comment: Son los campos de la tabla Evolucion